# SHA256 generating same hash value for every input

Tags: c

I am using SHA256 to generate hash value in C within a loop, along with the value for which hash is to be generated the counter variable of loop is also passed. As value of counter variable changes in every iteration so I expect SHA256 to return different hash every time. But it returns same hash every time.
Please Help!

Thanks in Advance

Code:

```
int generate_sha256hash { 
  int loop = 0; 
  unsigned char hash_paramters[2] = {0};
  unsigned char device_ids[2] = {0,0}; 
  hash_paramters[0] = 0; 
  unsigned char pass_string = "PASSWORD"; 

   for(loop = 1; loop < 10; loop++) {
     hash_paramters[1] = loop;
     memcpy((unsigned char)(&input_info[0]),(unsigned char )hash_paramters ,2); 
     memcpy((unsigned char)(&input_info[2]),(unsigned char )device_ids,2);
     memcpy((unsigned char)(&device_info[4]),(unsigned char*)au8defaultPwd,8); 

     printf("\n Generating Hash Value "); 

     hash_value = SHA256(device_info,14,au8HashValue); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post some code? I would guess that your counter is not updating or not being used correctly.

Comment: Thanks KryptoniteDove for response. I am adding code fragment for the same.

Comment: int generate_sha256hash
{
 int loop = 0;
 unsigned char hash_paramters[2] = {0};
 unsigned char device_ids[2] = {0,0};
 hash_paramters[0] = 0;
 unsigned char *pass_string = "PASSWORD";
 for(loop = 1; loop < 10; loop++)
 {hash_paramters[1] = loop;
  memcpy((unsigned char*)(&input_info[0]),(unsigned char *)hash_paramters ,2);
  memcpy((unsigned char*)(&input_info[2]),(unsigned char *)device_ids,2);
  memcpy((unsigned char*)(&device_info[4]),(unsigned char*)au8defaultPwd,8);

  printf("\n Generating Hash Value ");
  hash_value = SHA256(device_info,14,au8HashValue);
 }
}

Comment: Here value of password,device ids and 1st hash parameter remain same but value of 2nd hash parameter keeps on changing and has value of counter variable 'loop'.

Comment: I dont know C but I would increment loop as the last action in the loop so on the next iteration the loop is +1 of what it was before. Why not declare loop as an integer of 1 at the start of the function? again might be a C syntax thing just trying to offer some advice.

Comment: Where and what are `device_info` and `input_info`? It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

You change `input_info` in the loop (dependent on the counter), but don't use it for hash generation. You use only `device_info`).

And I take it that all the casts to `unsigned char` in the `memcpy` calls are actually casts to `unsigned char*`, as they should be. You've got other syntactic peculiarities in your code.

Comment: sha256hash { 
  int loop = 0;
  unsigned char hash_paramter[2] = {0};
  unsigned char device_id[2] = {0,0}; 
  unsigned char *HashValue = NULL;
  unsigned char pwd[8]= {'P','A','S','S','W','O','R','D'}; 
  hash_paramter[0] = 0;
  
   for(loop = 1; loop < 10; loop++) {
     hash_paramter[1] = loop;
     memcpy((unsigned char*)(&input_info[0]),(unsigned char *)hash_paramter ,2); 
     memcpy((unsigned char*)(&input_info[2]),(unsigned char* )device_id,2);
     memcpy((unsigned char*)(&input_info[4]),(unsigned char*)pwd,8); 

     hash_value = SHA256(input_info,14,HashValue); 
   }
}

Comment: thanks jpalecek for response,i hav pasted correct code now, please suggest.