# What is wrong here in hashing?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have created this unit test to notice a strange behavior, can you please help what is going on here?
Please notice that the second array has one more element.

```
 [Fact]
        public void Should_Have_Different_Values()
        {
            byte[] saltedPasswordBytes = new byte[]{5,18,99,52,68,25,32 };
            string hashedPassword1, hashedPassword2;
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                hashedPassword1= sha256.ComputeHash(saltedPasswordBytes, 0, 3).ToBase64String();
            }

        saltedPasswordBytes = new byte[] { 5, 18, 99, 52, 68, 25, 32 ,50};
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            hashedPassword2 = sha256.ComputeHash(saltedPasswordBytes, 0, 3).ToBase64String();
        }
        Assert.NotEqual(hashedPassword1, hashedPassword2);
    }
```

I am not sure where I am mistaken but I am using this to hash my data and it seems that it returns the same value regardless to the salt.
Is there anything wrong I am doing? or the Hash is not implemented or what? because Rfc2898DeriveBytes is working well.

Comment: "Very unlikely" and "tldr; no". Choose/use less bait-y titles. FWIW: Try with "salts" that differ in the first byte. I use the term loosely, because those are not actually salts (they are just some data being hashed). Then RTFM about what "0" and "3" are doing in context.

Comment: Water: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e59xaaz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHA256 generating same hash value for every input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279825/sha256-generating-same-hash-value-for-every-input)

Answer (score 6):

No, the SHA256 implementation (in .NET Core / .NET / Mono) is not 'brocken'. It is generally not an efficient use of time to assume that a library that millions of people rely on is broken and such click-bait titles or 'assertions' are best avoided when presenting problems.

The problem is **your code** is broken.

See the documentation for [HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e59xaaz(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Computes the hash value for the specified region of the specified byte array.

In this case `ComputeHash(dontCare, 0, 3)` only computes the hash of the first 3 bytes of the data. In the example code, the first three bytes of both "salts" are the same. Thus the result is *expected* to be the same.

Also, the data shown does not represent "salts". It would probably be good to refresh a bit before implementing password/security. Preferably, an existing/tested library should be used.